# How do I get public search:list data from Youtube Data API without using OAuth?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Im trying to use public (not private) YouTube data by using basic search:list query parameters to display public videos from a keyword. However I am asked to provide an authorization token.

Status code 401
{
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22)

Within Google's YouTube Data documentation, it states the following:

"Many requests search for publicly available content and therefore don't require authentication. -When you submit an unauthenticated request, you need to include the key argument that specifies the unique API key for your application." - YouTube > Data > Guides > Sample Requests

After following these directions, and using only my API key I still get the same 401 error.

How do I get around this? Is this even possible to get around for this particular use case?

(FYI: I got the calls to work by using an OAuth token using scopes that I don't need, but do not want my users to authenticate each hour, let alone even get asked to authenticate in the first place in order to display only public data...)

Comment: [edit] your question and add the code you're using